# as3 air get specific path to file on device

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using as3 air and testing on an android.

I need to able to load, thru a browse feature, the sd card 
OR
**I need to point directly to that file folder thru a path.**

I have successfully downloaded a zip file from a server. I can unzip it while testing on 
my desktop because I can browse to the correct path on desktop but not on phone. But I don't need the browse feature anyway, right now. I just need to be able to point to the applicationStorgeDirectory and the file in there. :)

I need the file var :)

```
var reader:ZipFileReader = new ZipFileReader();
    reader.open(file); /// Help :)
```

**UPDATE Sept 4th 2012 5pm**

---

I tried this code:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.zip");
trace(file.url); //path to the file
//assuming that function takes a string path
reader.open(file.url);
```

and I got this error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 46
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String
to an unrelated type flash.filesystem:File.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you a url to an existing file

[File url](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#url)

You could try something like this:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.zip");
trace(file.url); //path to the file
//assuming that function takes a string path
reader.open(file.url);
```

Comment: :( The function does not. 

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 46 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type flash.filesystem:File.

Comment: The error you are mentioning tells that you are using String where it expects File object, so you have used reader.open(file.url) and I could imagine that reader.open gets the File object so it should be reader.open(file);

Comment: This code worked. My issue was in the browse feature. I still could not find the right path through the browse. However this file DID POINT to the right place which allowed me to unzip my folder on my device. THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. I've tested.

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.zip");
trace(file.url);
reader.open(file);
```

Comment: This code is in there. Does it change things? var reader:ZipFileReader = new ZipFileReader();

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for all your effort!